# Bulk actions validation

Tags: validation, errors, data-collection

I need to design a solution in which a User can map fields from our App to an Integration. And actually, this bit is already prepared. The problem occurs in the fields.
Let's say my App has a field Nationality, in which the possible answers are: "Spain, France, Italy". But the Integration app takes only "Spain, Uruguay, Brazil". Whereas it's pretty easy for a single situation. How can I handle it for bulk actions?

Comment: What user or role would be handling this? Do you want this to be at an admin level (configuring your system's allowable values vs. the end system's values) or more like at the level of the person doing the data import (correcting invalid/mismatched values on a bulk level)?

Comment: @Izquierdo this would be an admin, or a user with special permissions.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds something like a find and replace all.

If the system finds one discrepancy, It's possible to have communication that points this out: "[this] choice is not valid, only 'B, C, D' can be accepted". Or simply 'invalid selection, chose a valid option'.

Then follow up with a way to apply this fix to the remainder of the form. It could be as soon as the user changes the input from invalid to valid, there is a new element that says 'apply to all instances' or 'X instances found, apply to all'. There are various ways you could communicate this in a UI, depends on your layout and design elements.

Word of caution when replacing lots of objects in a huge form: make sure the action can be undone as to not create a ton of rework.